# How can prove that $-(-x)=x$?

Tags: arithmetic

I need to prove the following property, but I don't know how: $$-(-x)=x.$$

Please help me. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: How have you had $-x$ defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$-(-x)=-(-x)+0=-(-x)+x+(-x)=[-(-x)+(-x)]+x=0+x=x$

Comment: if you swap $x + (-x)$ by $(-x) + x$ in the second step, you don't even need commutativity.

Comment: dear college, $x+(-x)=(-x)+x=0$, I am sure you understand what I've done

Comment: I know, just a bit cleaner this way. All fine anyways, mate. Also, some Groups don't need this (i.e. talk about left-inverse / right-inverse)

Comment: This property requires a simple confirmation, and I believe that he has given this example requires this thing, be shown in a simple way

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant in a group (or ring or field) and you're working axiomatically : use the uniqueness of additive inverse.

By definition, $\;-x\;$ is **the unique** element that fulfills $\;x+(-x)=0\;$ *and the other way around*, meaning: $\;x\;$ is the **unique** additive inverse of $\;-x\;$ , but then

$$-(-x)+(-x)\stackrel{\text{distributivity}}=(-1+1)(-x)=0\cdot x\stackrel{\text{hopefully you already proved this!}}=0$$

The above means that $\;-x\;$ is additive inverse **also** of $\;-(-x)\;$ , and from here that uniqueness forces $\;x(-x)=x\;$

Comment: Why force a Ring by using multiplication?!?

Comment: Seeing the level of he question most probably it is about the reals.

Comment: Still an unnecessary assumption. Seing he _has_ to prove this, it's more likely about Groups in general (maybe abelian). But nvm.

Comment: Perhpas in your experience @AlexR , not in mine. Here first year students must learn the basic axioms of fields to work their way into basic linear algebra. Much later will come groups and rings .

Comment: Well, over here students are confronted with the axiomatics of groups in linear algebra and this is expanded to rings. Proving the OP's assignment naturally emerges in the part about groups :)

Comment: Also here students are taught the basics of group and righ theory in Linear Algebra I... *at the end of the course* . At the beginning they're told about fields *only* to make, I'm sure, their way into the abstract part of it smoother. And what the OP asked belongs exactly to the part of fields. After this is trivial to exapand it to other algebraic structures.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'd remove my DV but unfortunately it's locked by now.

Comment: Never mind, though if you had followed my history in this site you'd see what my opinion on DV are.